# SVN status of S on some directories, but did not "svn switch"?

Tags: svn

I have a problem similar to this question, [Status "S" in Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866504/status-s-in-subversion), but I never executed an "svn switch..." command.

It happened on our dev server: What I did do was to try to upgrade a very outdated piece of software, by copying the old directory to a new directory, and adding the updated files to a new directory with the old directory's name. I forgot to do "svn move..." command. SVN got confused, and I tried deleting the new directory and renaming the old one.

When I still couldn't check-in, one of my co-workers suggested I do an "svn switch --relocate ..." because it thought some directories had a different username than the dev user I was logged in as. That fixed the dev repo.

But now my local repo has similar "S" status on different, unrelated directories, and it is the right user.

Is there a way to fix my local repo, or am I better just checking out a new copy and re-doing my last work?